# WCS as matplotlib projection for a data-cube slice loaded using astropy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy, pyfits

I have a FITS file named 'my_cube.fits' with WCS. The file has spatial information on axis 1 and 2 (X and Y) and spectral information on axis 3 (Z). When I load it using **astropy.io.fits**, the spectral axis is 0 and spatial axes are 1 and 2. The file is loaded like this:

```
    import astropy.io.fits as pyfits

    filename = 'my_cube.fits'
    my_data = pyfits.getdata(filename)
    my_header = pyfits.getheader(filename)
```

I have been using matplotlib to display data and I want to know how to display a single spectral frame of my data cube using its WCS. Let's say:

```
    from astropy.wcs import WCS
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    my_wcs = WCS(my_header)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=my_wcs)
    ax.imshow(my_data[5, :, :])

    plt.show()
```

If I just do that, I have:

```
    ...
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1005, in add_subplot
    a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 73, in __init__
    self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wcsaxes/core.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.patch = self.coords.frame.patch
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wcsaxes/frame.py", line 129, in patch
    self._update_patch_path()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wcsaxes/frame.py", line 115, in _update_patch_path
    self.update_spines()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wcsaxes/frame.py", line 192, in update_spines
    self['b'].data = np.array(([xmin, ymin], [xmax, ymin]))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wcsaxes/frame.py", line 40, in data
    self._world = self.transform.transform(self._data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wcsaxes/transforms.py", line 166, in transform
    world = self.wcs.wcs_pix2world(pixel_full, 1)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/astropy/wcs/wcs.py", line 1329, in wcs_pix2world
'output', *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/astropy/wcs/wcs.py", line 1231, in _array_converter
    return _return_single_array(xy, origin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/astropy/wcs/wcs.py", line 1212, in _return_single_array
"of shape (N, {0})".format(self.naxis))
    ValueError: When providing two arguments, the array must be of shape (N, 3)
```

Answer (score 10):

Your WCS object contains the two spatial axes *and* the spectral axis, since you initialized it with the full header (I assume your header also contains a spectral WCS solution). Thus, creating a 2D plot with just the spatial won't work, since your projection given to the subplot is 3D.

I haven't done this myself, nor do I have an example file, but the WCS documentation mentions that you can use [the sub function, or even the celestial functions](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/wcs/#subsetting-and-pixel-scales) to get the individual axes or the celestial (spatial) axes; these functions will return a WCS object with just those axes.

Thus, you can probably use the following:

```
my_wcs = WCS(my_header).celestial
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=my_wcs)
```

Comment: `celestial` is a property, not a function, so it doesn't need to be called

Comment: That will require a fix in the docs then; the API documentation is correct, but the part I link to calls it a function.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good use-case for [`spectral-cube`](http://spectral-cube.rtfd.org), which effectively wraps `astropy.io.fits` for cube uses.

Evert's solution, once corrected, will work, assuming you have [`wcsaxes`](https://wcsaxes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) installed.

To use `spectral_cube` for this, a simple example is:

```
cube = SpectralCube.read(filename)
cube[5,:,:].quicklook() # uses aplpy

# using wcsaxes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], projection=cube[5,:,:].wcs)
ax.imshow(cube[5,:,:]) # you may need cube[5,:,:].value depending on mpl version
```